# Windows shows more space used, than actually is

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell

When I check the size of a directory via properties in windows 7 it shows 8,12 GBs are used. Since I am unable to locate those gigabytes in the subdirectories I checked with the powershell which shows not even a gigabyte is used.

Here are some screenshots: (sorry for the german)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwtA9.jpg

( 1003734516 kB should be 957.23 mB )

Could anyone tell me what to do to get those numbers right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s really quite simple: Apply `-Force`. ;)

Otherwise, hidden items (like the `AppData` folder) will be skipped. You need to use `Get-ChildItem -Force -Recurse`.

And if you want to find all those space hogs, use a specialized tool like [WinDirStat](http://www.fosshub.com/WinDirStat.html).